# Azure Data Factory V2 SFTP Connection Issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a data factory using ADF V2 to get a file from SFTP server to blob storage. The pipeline has been running fine for a month but all of a sudden, I faced an error last week. Can someone let me know is there a way to fix this in ADF v2?

**Error:**

Activity Copy1 failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorNetworkIssue,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Meet network issue when connect to Sftp server '', 
SocketErrorCode: 'TimedOut'.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,
Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,Source=Renci.SshNet,'

Comment: Is your sftp server still responsive? this looks like a network issue at sftp server side instead of adf issue.

Comment: Hi Fang, thanks for your comment.. will check that